# Replace arrayList values from another arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have two arrayLists with one containing

an [[id,id],[id,id]...]
while the other contains [[id, String],[id,String]...]

I would like to replace the ids of the first arrayList with the associated String from the other list

Comment: Have you tried anything? Transform your second list into a Map<Id, String>, and everything will be much simpler (and faster).

Comment: Seems you're using a `List` where you should be using a `Map`

Comment: Did you make any effort? The idea would be to convert the second list to map (so that you won't have to traverse it over and over again and have O(1) read) and then iterate over the first one and insert the replaced values to a new array.

Comment: use Map your iteration will be reduced to O(n) for whole function and otherwise you have to use nested for loop that is very bad for performance.
If you want to do same If both id's are same though i don't know your comparison method if it is then you already have it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a list of lists (the question's phrasing is a bit unclear), you could iterate over the first list and find the matching element in the second list:

```
for (List f : firstList) {
    secondList.stream()
              .filter(s -> f.get(1).equals(s.get(0))
              .map(s -> s.get(1))
              .ifPresent(s -> f.set(1, s));
}
```